# Decomposition of matrix occuring in problem of finding $n+1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with pairwise equal inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I was toying with my intuition that there are always $n+1$ unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that every pair $v_i$ and $v_j$ ($i\neq j$) has the same angle between them. As those vectors are normalized this is equivalent to $$v_i\cdot v_j=\begin{cases} 1,& i=j \\m, & i\neq j \end{cases}$$ with $|m|<1$. So if $V$ is the $n\times (n+1)$ matrix whose columns are formed by the $v_i$ we have $$M:=V^TV=\begin{pmatrix}1 & m & \cdots &m \\m&1&\cdots&m\\ \vdots &&\ddots&\vdots \\ m&m&\cdots&1 \end{pmatrix}$$ $M$ is a $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ matrix and must be singular (as it is the product of two rank $n$ matrices). The sum of its rows is $(nm+1,nm+1,\ldots,nm+1)$. For $m=-\frac{1}{n}$ this is the null vector giving the required dot product $m$ as a function of $n$. E.g., for $n=2$, $m=-\frac{1}{2}$ corresponding to the expected angle of $120°=\arccos{-\frac{1}{2}}$. **Now I'm asking is there a matrix decomposition so that I can get $V$ back from the product $M$?** (I know that $V$ is not unique since I can freely rotate the vectors $v_i$ about an arbitrarily chosen fixed axis without changing their pairwise dot product.) I tried spectral decomposition of $M$ but that gives $n+1$ dimensional vectors and the $n$ nonzero eigenvalues of $M$ are all equal to $\frac{n+1}{n}$ which means that any linear combination of eigenvectors corresponding to that eigenvalue is also an eigenvector making the dot product between those eigenvectors rather arbitrary.

Comment: The spectral decomposition is good after you truncate the last column of the orthogonal matrix, and multiply the vectors by the square root of the eigenvalue

Comment: @Exodd Could you elaborate? With $n=3$ I get (using pari) eigenvalues [0,4/3,4/3,4/3] and eigenvector matrix [1, -1, -1, -1; 1, 1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 1, 0; 1, 0, 0, 1]. What exactly do I need to delete from that matrix?

Comment: first row from the eigenvector matrix. The vectors you're looking from will be the columns, properly normalized

Comment: @Exodd Hm, if I remove the first row from the eigenvector matrix I get a matrix with the first column being all 1's and the other three columns being Id(3). Therefore, the dot product of two different of those three vectors is 0 and no proper normalization can change that 0 to -1/3. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ${\mathbb R}^n$,  having $n+1$ unit vectors such that the angle between any two of them be equal
implies that the vectors individuate the vertices of a regular n-simplex inscribed in the unit sphere.
That means that the [cosine of the angle (your $m$) shall be $-1/n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Cartesian_coordinates_for_a_regular_n-dimensional_simplex_in_Rn).

$n$ of the vectors will be independent, while the (n+1)-th one will necessarily be dependent.
Therefore the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix
$$
M = V^{\,T} V
$$
will have null determinant.
But a $n \times n$ diagonal submatrix of it ($M'$)will be full-rank, symmetric (Hermitean) and positive definite,
being a matrix of inner products.
So it admits a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)
$$
M' =L L^{\,T}
$$
which is unique and therefore we shall have
$$
M' = L\,L^{\,T}  = V'^{\,T} V'\quad  \Rightarrow \quad V' = L^{\,T} 
$$
where $V'$ is the $n \times n$ matrix of $n$ of the (column) vectors.

The additional $n+1$ vector $v$ will be derived by solving
$$
V'^{\,T} v = Lv =  - \frac{1}{n}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1  \\   1  \\    \vdots   \\   1  \\\end{array}} \right)
$$

For example, for ${\mathbb R}^3$ we get
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 M' = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & { - 1/3} & { - 1/3}  \\
   { - 1/3} & 1 & { - 1/3}  \\
   { - 1/3} & { - 1/3} & 1  \\
\end{array}} \right) =  \\ 
  = L\,L^{\,T}  = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & 0 & 0  \\
   { - \frac{1}{3}} & {\frac{{2\sqrt 2 }}{3}} & 0  \\
   { - \frac{1}{3}} & { - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3}} & {\frac{{\sqrt 3 \sqrt 2 }}{3}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & { - \frac{1}{3}} & { - \frac{1}{3}}  \\
   0 & {\frac{{2\sqrt 2 }}{3}} & { - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3}}  \\
   0 & 0 & {\frac{{\sqrt 3 \sqrt 2 }}{3}}  \\
\end{array}} \right) \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
and
$$
V = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & { - \frac{1}{3}} & { - \frac{1}{3}} & { - \frac{1}{3}}  \\
   0 & {\frac{{2\sqrt 2 }}{3}} & { - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3}} & { - \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{3}}  \\
   0 & 0 & {\frac{{\sqrt 3 \sqrt 2 }}{3}} & { - \frac{{\sqrt 3 \sqrt 2 }}{3}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)
$$

Comment: Cool, thanks. The idea that I can just use $n$ vectors in $V$ to form a full rank $M$ hadn't crossed my mind. Now everything falls beautifully into place. Even uniqueness!

Comment: It's even possible to use Cholesky on the full $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ Matrix. octave gives for our $4\times 4$ example

    >chol(V)
    ans =
    
       1.0000  -0.3333  -0.3333  -0.3333
            0   0.9428  -0.4714  -0.4714
            0        0   0.8165  -0.8165
            0        0        0   0.0000

Comment: @diffset: glad that my answer is of help ! but I do not get what a Cholesky on $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ would give

Comment: It's just like Wikipedia says: Cholesky is also possible for positive **semidefinite** matrices. And indeed, when I did it for the three-dimensional case (the $(4\times 4)$ matrix) I got the same matrix V as you did except for an extra row of zeros. (It's not seen easily in my previous comment, I didn't manage to get multiline code into it…)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the existing answer, you can also extract your vectors by orthogonally diagonalizing $M$. The matrix $M$ has rank $n$ with two eigenvalues: The eigenvalue $\lambda := \frac{n+1}{n}$ of multiplicity $n$ and the eigenvalue $0$ of multiplicity one. Let $U$ be an orthogonal matrix such that

$$ U \begin{pmatrix} \lambda I_{n \times n} & 0_{n \times 1} \\ 0_{1 \times n} & 0 \end{pmatrix} U^T = M. $$

The first $n$ columns of $U$ form an orthonormal basis for the eigenspace of $M$ associated to $\lambda$ which is
$$\{ (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1})^T \, | \, x_1 + \dots + x_{n+1} = 0 \}. $$

Write
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{U}_{n \times n} & x_{n \times 1} \\ y_{1 \times n} & z \end{pmatrix}, V = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{V}_{n \times n} & v_{n+1} \end{pmatrix}.  $$

The equation $V^T V = M$ then becomes
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \hat{V}^T \hat{V} & \hat{V}^T v_{n+1} \\ v_{n+1} V^T & v_{n+1}^T v_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} = \lambda \begin{pmatrix}  \hat{U} \hat{U}^T & \hat{U} y^T \\ y \hat{U}^T & y \hat{y}^T \end{pmatrix}. $$

Hence if you take $\hat{V} = \sqrt{\lambda} \hat{U}^T, v_{n+1} = \sqrt{\lambda} y^T$ you get a solution. In other words, if you take the $n + 1$ **rows** of the eigenvector matrix $U$ (whose **columns** are the eigenvectors), forget the last coordinates and transpose, you get a solution. Since the eigenspace assosicated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $n$-dimensional, the matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \hat{U} \\ y \end{pmatrix} $$ is determined up to an orthogonal transformation of an $n$-dimensional subspace which corresponds to the freedom in rotating the columns of $V$ in an $n$-dimensional space.

---

Example: For $n = 2$, one possible decomposition is
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1/2 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & 1 & -1/2 \\ -1/2 & -1/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{pmatrix}}_{U} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \end{pmatrix}}_{U^T} $$

and the corresponding vectors are:
$$ v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}, \\
v_2 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} \end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, \\
v_3 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \end{pmatrix}^T = \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix} $$
[image]

Comment: This is what I had in mind originally. Somehow I thought that although the $n$ eigenvectors had "arbitrary" angles in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ their projection to a $\mathbb{R}^n$ subspace would make the angle corrrect. Just like if you take the standard base in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and project it onto the plane orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ you get the three vectors with 120° between each pair.